# Using if condition on data type

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to use a condition in my report based on the datatype. 
I have a 'date' field which is of date format in some cases and in String format in other cases. For string format I do a conversion to get the date. No conversion is required for those already in date format.

For example, I am trying this in the expression editor:

$F{start}.getClass()== "class java.util.Date" ? "Date" : "String"

But it is printing "String" for date fields. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is a type of `$F{start}` field? `java.lang.Object`?

Comment: $F{start} is of type java.util.Date

Comment: What is the meaning of this check in this case?

Comment: We need to do some conversion depending on the type. In this example I have just given "Date" and "String". In the actual report there will be some conversion expression instead of "date" and "String".

Comment: in the given example, it first checks the type of $F{start}, as it is of type 'java.util.Date' it should print "Date". But it is printing "String".

Answer (score 0):

OK I got the solution, I was missing the 'toString()' function:

(($F{start}.getClass()).toString()== "class java.util.Date")?"Date":"String"